Long time scale correlation and recurrence of dynamical system sequences
I have a dynamical system of the form y(k+1)=G(y(k)) where the states y(k) belong to F_2^n (where F_2 is the binary field) and G is a polynomial map in n variables in F_2^n. What can be said about correlations between successive states y(T+1), y(T+2),...y(T+m) with increasing T for any arbitrarily chosen initial state y(0)? What can be said about the minimal order m of linear recurrence relations of these sequences y(T+k) for large T? Here m is smallest such that y(T+m+j) can be expressed as a linear combination of previous m states for j=0,1,2.... Further, what can be said about the minimal order of recurrence relations in sequences y(0), y(T), y(2T),...y(kT) as T increases. Can one show that on the average, for maps or permutations defined by G in F_2^n, such correlations will increase with T and the orders m of recurrences will reduce? Or is this fact known or proven? Can somebody send any known references in past for this question?

Why don't you do some simple experiments with small values of $n$ (probably $n=2$ will already be interesting) and various polynomials? You'll probably learn a lot that way about how these recursions work.

Okay thanks. Good suggestion.

If T is sufficiently large close to the period of the sequence y(k) for a specific y(0) then both types of sequences y(T+k) and y(kT) will repeat frequently and hence the periods of these sequences y(T+k) as well as y(kT) will be much smaller than the period of the sequence y(k). Hence the order of linear recurrence of these sequences is likely to be smaller than the order of linear recurrence of y(k). This is one justification I could think of to support the conjectured hypothesis of the question.
